# Improve existing filter to exclude companies or company types

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

When scrolling through the job listings I often look for companies that are not in the consulting or outsourcing software development business - or in other words, companies that have their own product for which they need more developers.

It would be good, if the exclusion list for companies would not be a filter but would work like the "dismiss job" feature, so it is stored permanently and can also contain more than five companies, like the filter currently does.

Alternatively adding a tag to companies / job ads that discriminates between in-house and consulting work, and allowing to filter and this tag, would help to improve the matchmaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request has been noted but it's not currently on our roadmap.